# Get non empty element in XML using XPath expression including

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following and want to retrieve data where the 'FromEmail' is not empty

```
<FILE NAME="NewbusQuote">
   <REC NAME="level1">
        <FLD NAME="CoverPage"></FLD>
        <FLD NAME="FromEmail"></FLD>
       </REC>

    <REC NAME="leve2">
        <FLD NAME="CoverPage">Simple</FLD>
        <FLD NAME="FromEmail">email@gmail.com</FLD>
    </REC>


    <REC NAME="leve3">
        <FLD NAME="CoverPage"></FLD>
        <FLD NAME="FromEmail"></FLD>
    </REC>
</FILE>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Using `string-length()` comes to mind.

Comment: Get which data? What should the output look like?

Comment: @ Wrikken, I shall try that I just don't know how to go around it when names come to play.@ lwburk, sorry I forgot to mention proper, the non empty FromEmail is the one I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath

```
/FILE/REC/FLD[@NAME = 'FromEmail']
```

will return FLD elements with attribute FromEmail, but this query

```
/FILE/REC/FLD[@NAME = 'FromEmail']/text()
```

will return only text content of second FromEmail element.

XPath in general doesn't retrieve empty elements (it's the same like if they were 
`<FLD NAME="FromEmail" />`).

to get all data from all elements with FromEmail atributte, use this

```
/FILE/REC//FLD[@NAME = 'FromEmail']/text()
```

Hope it helps